# nm-applet reports "No network devices available" - how to fix?

Tags: 16.04, networking, kernel, network-manager

I'm having strange issue on my Ubuntu MATE 16.04.5 LTS which is installed on external USB 3.0 drive.
It uses GRUB installed in MBR.
It has all updates installed.
The file-system is clean (forced `fsck` from other Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system).

Network Manager applet (`nm-applet`) says the following:

> No network devices available
>   [image: No network devices available]

But if I try to boot it with QEMU-KVM (`sudo kvm -drive file=/dev/sdc,format=raw -m 1512`) then it finds the network (default virtual Intel 82540EM driven by `e1000e` kernel module).

I see that system uses 4.15.0-33-generic kernel in `uname -r` and by package list:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux | grep 4.15
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-33                       4.15.0-33.36~16.04.1                         all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic               4.15.0-33.36~16.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic                 4.15.0-33.36~16.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic               4.15.0-33.36~16.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

What is interesting - the related HWE package is not installed.

Running `debsums -c -s -a` does not show any suspicious output.

I have purged and installed back the NetworkManager and its related stuff:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
sudo apt-get install indicator-network indicator-network-tools network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

But It does not help.

Is it possible that kernel causes problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be kernel issue.

I have rebooted with previous 4.4.0-138-generic kernel and network is working again.

So I removed the 4.15 kernel with

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep 4.15 | grep linux | awk '{print $2}')
sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic
```

to prevent future unpredictable behavior.

After reboot all network devices were recognized successfully.

Comment: Problem with network devices started in 4.15.0-29, and was still a problem in -36. Upgrading to 18.10 seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I do not plan to upgrade to non-LTS Ubuntu version. Ubuntu MATE 16.04.5 LTS is stable and works great for me. Downgrading kernel helped anyway.